# Dismiss active snack bar on Fragment destroy

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-fragments, android-snackbar

**How can I make sure any visible Snackbar (specially those with snackbar.length_indefinite) will be dismissed once fragment is destroyed?**

Should I use a common globar variable for all Snackbars and call dismiss on that? Something like below?

**Fragment1.java**

```
private Snackbar snackbar;

@Override
public onDestroy(){
    snackbar.dismiss();
}

public Method1(){
    snackbar = Snackbar.make(ActivityMain.coordinatorLayout, "Text 1", snackbar.length_indefinite);
    snackbar.show();
}

public Method2(){
    snackbar = Snackbar.make(ActivityMain.coordinatorLayout, "Text 2", snackbar.length_indefinite);
    snackbar.show();
}
//coordinatorLayout is a static variable in ActivityMain which stores reference to the CoordinatorLayout
```

Answer (score 5):

> How can I make sure any visible Snackbar (specially those with
>   snackbar.length_indefinite) will be dismissed once fragment is
>   destroyed?

To dismiss that call it onDestroy(); method **as you have done**.

> Should I use a common globar variable for all Snackbars and call
>   dismiss on that? Something like below?

**Yes,** you can do that way because snackbar is **used many times** in your class. so it is better to declare it global.

check more detail of snack bar on [developer.android.com](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/Snackbar.html#make%28android.view.View,%20java.lang.CharSequence,%20int%29)

Comment: Though it is an old post, just want to add that having a glibal snackbar variable will not work if you plan to show multiple snackbar (not simultaneously) in a fragment lifespan.

Answer (score 1):

While having global `SnackBar` and making sure that you close it in `onDestroyView()` is a fine approach.

I suggest wrapping your Fragment XML layout in the CoordinatorLayout and passing the fragment root view to the `Snackbar.make` function, like so:

fragment_your_fragment.xml

```xml
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<!-- Your Layout Content  -->

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**YourFragment.kt**

```kotlin
fun showSnackbar() {
    Snackbar.make(requireView(), "Your message", Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE).show()
}
```

This way, when you open another fragment(add it to the stack), `Snackbar` will be dismissed automatically